# Is it possible to have different workflows in Jira swimlanes?

Tags: jira

I want to have a single Jira board with swimlanes where each swimlane has a different workflow. For example, swimlane #1 uses: analysis/dev/test. And swimlane #2 uses: to do/dev/test/UAT/done.

This does not seem to be possible. Is that correct? Is it possible with custom programming?

Answer (score 0):

That is possible, by manually configuring the swimlanes.

You can combine as many tickets as you want on a single board, by using an appropriate issue filter. If these tickets have different workflows, that is no problem. Of course, if you want to have one column for each workflow status, you will have columns that only some tickets can use, but Jira will indicate that.

If you then want to group tickets with different workflows in different swimlanes, you can create swimlanes based on suitable JQL conditions. Tickets with different workflows will be from different projects and/or have a different type, so you can use that to set up the JQL conditions.

You will have to set up these conditions manually (you cannot directly create one swimlane per workflow), but that is only a one-time setup.

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible. You can only have one workflow per board (Kanban or Scrum). You can use JQL to control what you see in the swimlanes but not to alter the workflow.